# how can javascript Twilio browser client detect that recording has actually started when the beep is played?

Tags: twilio

I can successfully record voice within the browser using Twilio.js lib.

I would like to display a count down timer once the recording begins which happens when the "beep" is played.

Is there any way for the client lib to detect the recording start / beep so that I can start count down timer?

Answer (score 1):

Twilio evangelist here.

There is no way for the client to tell you that a "beep" has occurred.  What you could do is at the beginning of the call, prompt the user to press a button on the web page to start recording.  That button press can do two things:

1. [send a DTMF tone](https://www.twilio.com/docs/client/connection#sendDigits) to Twilio which you can listen for using the  [`<Gather>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/gather) verb.  Once the gather completes you can tell Twilio to start recording.
2. starts a timer on the client.

The timing between the client and exactly when the client starts won't be 100% in sync, but it should be pretty close.

Hope that helps.